# Nginx and tsung - how to best to point to html output directory

Tags: nginx, tsung

I am using for load testig and the output directory has this format.

```
~/.tsung/log/20120529-0139/report.html
```

How can i have nginx point to that directory so I can load the html files?

The portion of the path that is variable is 20120529-0139.  Its a date/time stamp.

So, how will that work in the nginx config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know nginx specific for this, but in case of apache sharing reports can be easily done via creating separate dir for tsung-reports in apache [document root](http://webhostingneeds.com/Setting_document_root_in_nginx), then point created dir upon tsung test start

```
tsung -f test.xml -l /var/www/html/tsung/ start
Starting Tsung
"Log directory is: /var/www/html/tsung/20120530-0853"
```

and then accessing report:

```
http://servername/tsung/20120530-0853/graph.html
```